# Trying to send screenshot over sockets using pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to send screenshot, but when I get the screenshot I get this picture on my screen, instead of normal one...

What am I doing wrong?

Server:

```
elif data.decode().lower() == 'screenshot':
    try:
        image = pyautogui.screenshot()
        client.send(image.tobytes())
    except:
        pass
```

Client:

```
elif msg.lower() == 'screenshot':
    try:
        data = client.recv(1310720000)
        data = Image.frombytes('RGB', (1280, 720), data)
        while os.path.exists(r'c:\ScreenshotsPY\Screenshot ' + str(n) + '.png') == True:
            n += 1
        data.save(r'c:\ScreenshotsPY\Screenshot ' + str(n) + '.png')
        data.show()
    except:
        print('Screenshot has been failed')
```

Picture:
[image]

Comment: What is breaking the image? Does the screenshot look normal before sending it via socket? Does it break after the socket? 

Have you tried using `Image.frombytes(image.tobytes())`? Problem might before socket is even used.

Comment: Is it by chance condensing the image before it is sending it passes it? Modern screens are pretty high resolution.

Comment: @jhc sry i answer too late i dont know how to use this website, but it break after the socket, i tried now. not working. when i do image.show() in server it is normal

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse idk wdym

Comment: Sorry missed a / in my comment. There is a good chance the screenshot is being condensed before it is being sent because of how large it is in terms of memory.

Comment: Yeah, I would try to break the images into manageable buffer sizes, and then reconstruct.

Comment: @jhc how exactly i dont understand im pretty new... can u edit my post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the size and mode variables are correct, then maybe when sending the pictures some of the pixels come out as trash because utf-8 doesn't have a representation for them. Try to send the data in base64 and than decode on arrival like this:

At client and server:

```
`import base64`
```

At client:

```
client.send(base64.b64encode(image.tobytes()))
```

At server:

```
data = Image.frombytes('RGB', (1280, 720), base64.b64decode(data))
```

I don't know for sure that this is the problem but it did solve some problems for me.